# Move td to new column

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table like that:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|1</td>
    <td id="abc|1">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|1</td>
    <td id="def|1">def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|2</td>
    <td id="abc|2">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|2</td>
    <td id="def|2">def</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

How can I move the `tds` with the suffix `|2` to the right, so adding a 3rd column? Also, the remaining "empty" td "some column|2" and "another column|2" should be removed completely.

The final result should look as follows:

[image]

This is the desired code:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|1</td>
    <td id="abc|1">abc</td>
    <td id="abc|2">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|1</td>
    <td id="def|1">def</td>
    <td id="def|2">def</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

This is my approach, which doesn't work:

```
$("table td:nth-child(2)[id$=2]").after("table td:nth-child(2)");
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/Lvqjnj4n/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve what you want:

```js
// Values for new column to be added
var newVals = $("table td:nth-child(2)[id$=2]");

$("table td:nth-child(2)[id$=1]").each(function (ind) {
  if (ind < newVals.length) {
    // Get New Element to add
    var newElement = newVals[ind];
    // Remove original row for this element
    $(newElement).parent().remove();
    // Append to new column
    $(this).after($(newElement));                
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|1</td>
    <td id="abc|1">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|1</td>
    <td id="def|1">def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ome column|2</td>
    <td id="abc|2">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|2</td>
    <td id="def|2">def</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code

```js
var firstTd = $("table").find("tr:nth-child(3) > td:nth-child(2)");
var secondTd = $("table").find("tr:nth-child(4) > td:nth-child(2)");

$("table").find("tr:nth-child(3), tr:nth-child(4)").remove();
$("table").find("tr:nth-child(1)").append(firstTd);
$("table").find("tr:nth-child(2)").append(secondTd);
```

```css
table, tr, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|1</td>
    <td id="abc|1">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|1</td>
    <td id="def|1">def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|2</td>
    <td id="abc|2">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|2</td>
    <td id="def|2">def</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the ids using underscore as a delimeter like this: `abc_1` and try this code ([FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/kapantzak/Lvqjnj4n/7/)):

HTML

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|1</td>
    <td id="abc_1" class="text-cell">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|1</td>
    <td id="def_1" class="text-cell">def</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>ome column|2</td>
    <td id="abc_2" class="text-cell">abc</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|2</td>
    <td id="def_2" class="text-cell">def</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

jQuery

```
var tbl = $('table');
tbl.find('tr').each(function() {
    var row = $(this);
  var txtCell = row.find('.text-cell');
  var cellId = txtCell.attr('id');
  var cellArr = cellId.split('_');
  var idLeft = cellArr[0];
  var idRight = cellArr[1];
  if (idRight == '1') {
      var child = $('#' + idLeft + '_2');
      var cTxt = child.text();
      child.closest('tr').remove();
      row.append('<td>' + cTxt  + '</td>');      
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Heres how i would do it:

```
<script>
   $("table [id$='|2']").each(function(){
     var id = $(this).attr('id').split('|')[0];
     $("#"+id+"\\|1").parent().append('<td>'+$(this).html()+'</td>');
     $(this).parent().remove();
   });
</script>
```