# Adding elements within new TD

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this table structure:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="abc|1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|1</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="def|1" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>some column|2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="abc|2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>another column|2</td>
    <td>
      <input type="text" id="def|2" />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

I want the both right columns of the last 2 rows to be added to the right, as a new column.

So that it looks like that:

[image]

In my approach ([inspired here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37594430/move-td-to-new-column/37597485)) the elements are just added **within an existing column**, instead of creating a new column `td`:

```
var newVals1 = $("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=2]");

$("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=1]").each(function(ind) {
  if (ind < newVals1.length) {
    var newElement = newVals1[ind];
    $(newElement).parent().parent().remove();
    $(this).after($(newElement));
  }
});
```

[FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/rja5mcuc/).

So how can I add the elements within a new `td`?

So instead of:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" id="abc|1">
  <input type="text" id="abc|2">
  <input type="text" id="abc|3">
</td>
```

I want:

```
<td>
  <input type="text" id="abc|1">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" id="abc|2">
</td>
<td>
  <input type="text" id="abc|3">
</td>
```

Simply doing

```
$(this).after("<td>" + newElement + "</td>")
```

results in

```
[object HTMLInputElement]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=2]").each(function(i) {
    var $newCell = $(this).wrap('<td></td').parent();
    var $newRow = $("table td:nth-child(2) [id$=1]").eq(i).parents('tr');
    $(this).parents('tr').remove();
    $newRow.append($newCell);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9uathy82/5/

Comment: When I do `$(this).parents('tr').append('<td>' + $(newElement) + '</td>')`, I get `[object Object]`.

Comment: @user1170330 Yeah you don't need to append the jQuery object of the element, just append the HTML. See my updated Fiddle.

Comment: In your fiddle, the 2nd element is outside of a `td`. It's just inside of the `tr`. Is it possible to place that element inside of a new `td`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use,

```
$(this).closest("tr").append($(newElement).wrap("<td></td>"));
```

- Get the parent tr and append the new element which is wrapped in td element

Comment: In your fiddle, the 2nd element is outside of a `td`. It's just inside of the `tr`. Is it possible to place that element inside of a new `td`?

Comment: You have already accepted one answer. Isn't it working for you?